# How to play a wav file in a livecode generated android application

Tags: android, wav, nvidia, tablet, livecode

A wav sound file imported as a control into a livecode application plays as expected in the Windows generated version of the program, but not in the android generated version on a nVidia tablet. The wav file will play by itself when copied to the android tablet.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a WAV file onto your card, an audioClip object is created.  The LiveCode Dictionary says this object type is supported only on Mac, Windows, and Linux, i.e. Desktop platforms.

On mobile platforms, you'd need to include the WAV files in the "Copy Files" section of the Application Standalone Settings, and you can play the WAV files in script using the **mobilePlaySoundOnChannel command**.

Please look up **mobilePlaySoundOnChannel** in the LiveCode Dictionary for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try it.